# Magento 2.3 - setup:upgrade Schema creation/updates error in DefinitionAggregator.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-upgrade

I am trying to setup:upgrade but its giving me this error

```
Undefined index: version in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php on line 91
```

I am not able to trace it. How do I fix this?

Comment: It was a MySQL error. 

SHOW variables LIKE 'version' was returning blank output. I had to re-install MySQL server and problem solved.